# isdigit and scanf with infinite loop

Tags: c

what is wrong with my program? When I enter a number for the first time, it print the statement inside if, but when I exit the program and re-enter with a char, then it print the statement inside else and the loop never exit when I keep inputting numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    char y;
    for(x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
            puts("Please enter a number:");
            scanf("%c",&y);
            if(isdigit(y))
            {
                    printf("Y is a digit!\n");
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                    printf("Y is not a number, please enter another number:\n");
                    scanf("%d",&y);
            }
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mistake in your program, particularly in the `else` part. You used `scanf("%d",&y);` instead of `scanf("%c",&y);`.

`%d` is used for an integer, but the declaration of `y` is char, so you must use `%c`.

Comment: He could use `%hhd` to store a number to a `char`. Though that's reaching, and does not support the semantics he seems to want.

Comment: Oh yeah, but even that, the loop wont let me enter the second number

Answer (score 0):

`"%c"` does *not* skip leading white-space.

With `scanf("%c",&y);`, code reads the first `char` that comes along which on the 2nd pass is likely a `'\n'` from the previous entry.  To make `scanf("%c",&y);` slip leading white-space, use:

```
scanf(" %c",&y); // Note added space.
```

To read a number into `char`, use the following as suggested by @Deduplicator.  Note it does not need a leading `' '` as all format specifiers ignore leading white-space except for 3: `"%c"`, `"%["`, `"%n"`

```
scanf("%hhd",&y);
```

Of course, code could simply use `int y`.
Note: `isdigit()` is only valid for 0 to `UCHAR_MAX` (e.g. 255) and `EOF`.

```
int y;
puts("Please enter a number:");
scanf("%d",&y);
if(isdigit(y))
```